# Find links in a website chart according to chart?

Tags: html, curl, charts, grep, wget

So I found [this website](https://cros-updates-serving.appspot.com/) that has a chart that I want to download something from a grid in the chart (For example codename volteer and it's relative recovery image links)

How can I use wget and grep to download the latest image?

Comment: Please read [ask] then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly keep in mind that websites generally use HTML which belong to Chomsky Type-2, whilst regular expression (used among others in `grep`) are destined for working Chomsky Type-3 contraptions, therefore situation might arise when they will not suffice. For further discussion see [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Question which arise, will regular expression suffice for your use case?
After inspecting website link to download are quite predictable, page source excerpt

```
<a href="https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chromeos/recovery/chromeos_13816.82.0_volteer_recovery_stable-channel_mp-v6.bin.zip">90</a>
<a href="https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chromeos/recovery/chromeos_13904.55.0_volteer_recovery_stable-channel_mp-v6.bin.zip">91</a>
<a href="https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chromeos/recovery/chromeos_13982.88.0_volteer_recovery_stable-channel_mp-v6.bin.zip">92</a> 
<a href="https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chromeos/recovery/chromeos_14092.77.0_volteer_recovery_stable-channel_mp-v8.bin.zip">93</a>    
<a href="https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chromeos/recovery/chromeos_14150.87.0_volteer_recovery_stable-channel_mp-v8.bin.zip">94</a>
```

thus it is possible to use regular expression `https[^"]*volteer[^"]*zip` which will find URLs which starts with `https` contain `volteer` and ends with `zip`. I use `[^"]*` as `"` delimiter is used for `<a>`'s `href` value and I do not want to include them in match. You might do your task as follows

1. use `wget` to download linked site as `site.html`
2. use `grep -o 'https[^"]*volteer[^"]*zip'` to get urls
3. use `tail -1` to get last (latest) of them
4. use `wget` to download it

Comment: Thank you, this helps greatly with my app!